# Trying to set xAxis extremes using highcharts-vue wrapper

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I use the highcharts-vue wrapper (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue) to display a chart in my project. Now I'm dynamically adding new data to the already existing data. 
(Originally I believe the `addPoint` function is used, but I already switched to pushing it to the `series` array.)

Now when I add one more element to data the selected/displayed range stays the same, but I wish to set it anchored to the right, so the new pushed data point appears (without having to shift the selected range manually).

In this highcharts example it's very much what I need, except for it not updating automatically at an interval, but on clicking a button. 
https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

I thought, I could work around it by using setExtremes on xAxis, but I get an error, that xAxis doesn't exist. Something like in this example.
http://jsfiddle.net/wkBwW/16/

So I think it's because I have to change the values differently or call an update differently because of the wrapped version.

```html
<template>
    <div class="chartcard">
      <highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="chartOptions" ></highcharts>
      <button v-on:click="addPoint" key="nextbutton"> add data </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import chartdatajson from "../assets/chart_data.json"
import {Chart} from 'highcharts-vue'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock'

stockInit(Highcharts);

let groupingUnits = [['week', [1]], ['month', [1]]];

function getOhlcAndVolume(data) {
...
}
let dataOhlcVolume = getOhlcAndVolume(chartdatajson);


export default {
  name: 'ChartCard',
  props: {
  },
  components: {
    highcharts: Chart 
  },
  methods: {
    rescale: function(){
      this.chartOptions.rangeSelector.selected = 0;
    },
    addPoint: function() {
      let somedata = this.test_add_data.shift();
      let ohls = somedata.slice(0,5);
      let volume = [somedata[0], somedata[5]];
      this.chartOptions.series[0].data.push(ohls);
      this.chartOptions.series[1].data.push(volume);

      // this.chartOptions.xAxis.max = somedata[0]
      this.chartOptions.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1554048000000 , somedata[0])
    },
  },
  data () {
    return {
      test_add_data: [[1556812800000,262,265,260.5,265,30200],[1557072000000,260,260,258,259,33688],[1557158400000,259.5,263,259,262.5,25686]],
      chartOptions: {
        rangeSelector: {
          selected: 0
        },
        title: { text: 'Some Title' },
        yAxis: [{...
        }],
        xAxis: {
        },
        series:
          [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: dataOhlcVolume.ohlc,
            dataGrouping: {
              units: groupingUnits
            }
          }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: dataOhlcVolume.volume,
            yAxis: 1,
            dataGrouping: {
              units: groupingUnits
            }
          }]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example with setting extremes in vue app: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-nutgx. As you can see `setExtremes()` method has to be invoked on `chart.xAxis` instance.

You can get chart reference following this approach:

```
  data() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          events: {
            load: (function(self) {
              return function() {
                self.chart = this; // saving chart reference in the component
              };
            })(this)
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    };
  }
```

This way you can reference `xAxis.setExtremes()` like that:

```
  methods: {
    setNewExtremes: function() {
      this.chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1525872600000, 1528291800000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, I can access `setExtremes` now!
Additionally, I had to deactivate the `rangeSelector: { selected: 0 }` option in my code and now it's working.